# Button becomes unclickable after adding inline css

Tags: html, css, vue.js

The CSS of my buttons kept getting overridden by user agent stylesheet, hence I overrode it with inline CSS. However, the buttons become unclickable afterwards.. My code is as follows. Thanks for your help!

```
<button class="register-continue-with-google register-continue-with" >Sign Up with Google</button>
```

[Before inline CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftFEI.png)

```
<button class="register-continue-with-google register-continue-with" style="background-color: transparent; border-color: transparent;">Sign Up with Google</button>
```

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OF79w.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is not like what you are thinking, the button is still clickable but you don't see any visual on the front until you add any functionality to it.
You can see here -

```js
test = () => {
document.getElementById('testdiv').style.backgroundColor='blue';
};
```

```css
#testdiv {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

button {
cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="testdiv"></div>
        <button
            class="register-continue-with-google register-continue-with"
            style="background-color: transparent; border-color: transparent"
            onclick="test()"
        >
    <br />
            Click me!
        </button>
```

You can add-

```
cursor:pointer;
```

to the button css and it will look clickable just like a link.